# Can Akka grpc consume data from non-Akka service

Tags: java, akka, protocol-buffers, akka-stream, akka-grpc

I'm having trouble to understand the fundamentals of Akka grpc. In Akka documentation I see examples of Akka protobuf client consuming service from Akka protobuf server.

Can I use Akka though to consume data from a non-Akka protobuf service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/client/walkthrough.html):

> To use a service, such as the Hello World service described in the server documentation, you only need the protobuf definition (the .proto files) of the service. No additional dependencies to the server project are needed.

I'm reading this to mean that if you have the .proto, it doesn't matter what the other end was implemented in.

Comment: I'm not sure that text means that. It looks more like as if it is saying that you don't need other libraries/frameworks. Have you ever tried to consume a non-akka protobuf service?

Comment: It says that the only thing the client needs is the proto.  If an akka-grpc client can't consume from a service given the proto, the proto in question doesn't match or there's a bug in at least one of akka-grpc or the server.  I have successfully used akka-grpc to communicate with k8s operators written in golang.